# jQuery Drag and Drop - How to add image into variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a simple drag and drop game that allows you to match the image to the correct body part.

With help from an open source so far I've been able to implement numbers and text, however instead of the numbers '1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" I want these to be images in the box, that will then be draggable to the text.

Below is the variable that is used to create the numbers, I'm wondering how I would change the numbers to images?

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

for ( var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
$('<div>' + numbers[i] + '</div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id',       'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
  containment: '#content',
  stack: '#cardPile div',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
} );
}
```

I've also attached a [Live Link](http://itssjp.co.uk/dragdrop)
to allow you to better understand.

Thanks

Comment: I dont know the answer but i am a crazy cat person.

Comment: Are the images fixed or will always be changed. You will need to save the target for each image before you actually implement what you want.

Comment: @adirohan No they will be the same 5 images, it's probably something easy but I can't get my head around how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
var imgs = [ '/images/1.gif','/images/2.gif','/images/3.gif','/images/4.gif','/images/5.gif','/images/6.gif' ];

numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

for ( var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
$('<div><img  src="' + imgs[numbers[i] - 1] + '" alt="alt"/></div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] ).attr( 'id',         
   'card'+numbers[i] ).appendTo( '#cardPile' ).draggable( {
  containment: '#content',
  stack: '#cardPile div',
  cursor: 'move',
  revert: true
 } );
}
```

There are obvious ways to get around using an array of imgs but this was just an example.

Comment: Thank you, this works great but how do I get a different image for each div? Sorry I may have explained it wrong, there will be 5 different images

Comment: @user1679857, in my opinion , this will generate wrong images , since he is generating a random sequence of numbers whereas you harcoded the image names.

Comment: his random numbers could all be linked to the index of an array of images.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just set the css background image property for all divs

```
    var numbers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ];
    numbers.sort( function() { return Math.random() - .5 } );

    for ( var i=0; i<6; i++ ) {
      $('<div></div>').data( 'number', numbers[i] )
           .attr( 'id','card'+numbers[i] )
           .appendTo( '#cardPile' )
           .draggable({
             containment: '#content',
             stack: '#cardPile div',
             cursor: 'move',
             revert: true
           })
           .css('background-image', 'url(' + numbers[i] + '.png)');
    }
```

You need to have 1.png, 2.png, 3.png, 4.png, 5.png in the same folder .

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, however after placing the images all in the same folder this doesn't seem to append any images into the div